# VS 2010 & .NET 4.0 can support this feature?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem about designing my application. I have a webservice with methods. Methods will return a encrypted binary data. Data after decrypting is a list of objects. Object can be Object1, or Object2, or Object3 which depend on called method.

I want to write only one function which return a List of object I want depend on called method. Example:

```
public static List<TKey> Generate(DataType type)
        {
            List<TKey> l = new List<TKey>();
            switch (type)
            {
                case DataType.String:
                    byte[] data = Decrypt(MyWebService.GetData1());
                    l = (List<TKey>)data;

                case DataType.Int:
                    byte[] data = Decrypt(MyWebService.GetData1());
                    l = (List<TKey>)data;
            }
            return l;
        }
```

Note: this function has error when building. I give this function so that you can understand my purpose.

My Purpose is here:

```
List<string> myString = Generate(DataType.String);
List<int> myInt = Generate(DataType.Int);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I want to know I can write a function like this because my function has error. Thanks.

Comment: What's the error? I've given this a -1 because you've said there is an error, but not give us any error description.

Comment: Please include compiler (or runtime) error messages/symptoms in questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely looking for a generic method:

```
public static List<T> Generate<T>()
{
   byte[] data = Decrypt(MyWebService.GetData1());
   List<T> l = Deserialize<T>(data);   
   return l;
}
```

You also will need a type specific deserialization method (`Deserialize` in the example), which would do the actual work of converting an arbitrary byte array into a list of a specific type - since it is entirely up to you how that mapping should work (the framework can't know really) you will have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Please help me to write Deserialize method. If I use List<T> l = (List<T>)(data); -> I will get compile error: "Cannot convert type 'byte[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'". PLease help me. Thanks.

Comment: what kind of binary data do you have? Was this generated using a built in serializer (if so which?) or by hand?

Comment: Assume that T is int or string. HOw to do that? THanks.

Comment: @LuLu it still would depend on the binary representation of that data (whatever Decrypt returns), without that knowledge you cannot deserialize.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a templated function so that you can pass in the type you'd like for the collection. I'd suggest first deserializing the objects into a `List<Object>` collection and then calling `ConvertAll()` to explicitly convert them to the type you'd like. There are a pair of includes here for `MemoryStream` and `BinaryFormatter`. `BinaryFormatter` will deserialize your byte array into an object which you must explicitly cast to the type you were expecting. I assume it always starts out as a list of objects. From there I use a delegate to explicitly cast each object into the type passed in via the parameter `TKey`.

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public List<TKey> Generate<TKey>()
{
    byte[] theData = MyWebService.GetData1();
    List<Object> theList = (List<Object>)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(new MemoryStream(theData));

    return theList.ConvertAll(i => (TKey) i);
}
```

**Sample Usage**

```
List<string> theStringList = Generate<string>();
List<int> theIntList = Generate<int>();
```